# How to change label numbers : polarplots

Tags: graphics, pstricks, pst-plot

As per answer received in previous post, i'm able to draw graph mentioned below using tex file :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.1cm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.1cm}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)%             user coordinates (is cm by default)
\psaxes[labels=none,axesstyle=polar,ticklinestyle=dashed,tickcolor=black!40](0,0)(-4,-4)(4,4)
\psaxes(0,0)(-4,-4)(4,4)%                  for the labels
\psset{fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.5}
\pswedge[fillcolor=green]{2.2}{120}{150}%  radius;startAngle;endAngle
\pswedge[fillcolor=yellow]{1.5}{150}{180}
\pswedge[fillcolor=red]{1.25}{180}{210}
\pswedge[fillcolor=red]{1.8}{210}{240}
\pswedge[fillcolor=green!100!white!80]{1.5}{240}{270}
\pswedge[fillcolor=orange]{2.4}{270}{300}
\pswedge[fillcolor=magenta]{2.2}{300}{330}
\pswedge[fillcolor=cyan]{0.6}{330}{360}
\pswedge[fillcolor=green](4.25;90){0.5}{70}{110} \rput(4.9;90){One}
\pswedge[fillcolor=yellow](4.25;80){0.5}{70}{110}\rput(4.9;80){Two}
\pswedge[fillcolor=red](4.25;70){0.5}{70}{110}   \rput(4.9;70){Three}
\pswedge[fillcolor=blue](4.25;60){0.5}{70}{110}  \rput[b](4.9;60){four}
\psset{opacity=1}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Can you please suggest, how can i change LABEL values on AXIS from 1, 2, 3, 4 to 25,50,75 and 100

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the second `psaxes` to

```
 \psaxes[dx=1,dy=1,Dx=25,Dy=25](0,0)(-4,-4)(4,4)%
```

Note that `dx` and `dy` change the value of the tickmarks, and `Dx` and `Dy` change the tickmarks themselves; have a look at the [`pst-plot`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pst-plot) documentation for further details.

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: latex
% arara: dvips
% arara: ps2pdf
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: true, trace: on}
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)%             user coordinates (is cm by default)
    \psaxes[labels=none,axesstyle=polar,ticklinestyle=dashed,tickcolor=black!40](0,0)(-4,-4)(4,4)
    \psaxes[dx=1,dy=1,Dx=25,Dy=25](0,0)(-4,-4)(4,4)%                  for the labels
    \psset{fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.5}
    \pswedge[fillcolor=green]{2.2}{120}{150}%  radius;startAngle;endAngle
    \pswedge[fillcolor=yellow]{1.5}{150}{180}
    \pswedge[fillcolor=red]{1.25}{180}{210}
    \pswedge[fillcolor=red]{1.8}{210}{240}
    \pswedge[fillcolor=green!100!white!80]{1.5}{240}{270}
    \pswedge[fillcolor=orange]{2.4}{270}{300}
    \pswedge[fillcolor=magenta]{2.2}{300}{330}
    \pswedge[fillcolor=cyan]{0.6}{330}{360}
    \pswedge[fillcolor=green](4.25;90){0.5}{70}{110} \rput(4.9;90){One}
    \pswedge[fillcolor=yellow](4.25;80){0.5}{70}{110}\rput(4.9;80){Two}
    \pswedge[fillcolor=red](4.25;70){0.5}{70}{110}   \rput(4.9;70){Three}
    \pswedge[fillcolor=blue](4.25;60){0.5}{70}{110}  \rput[b](4.9;60){four}
    \psset{opacity=1}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Following the comments, if you only want positive numbers on the axis ticks then you can use

```
\psaxes[dx=1,dy=1,Dx=25,Dy=25](0,0)(0,0)(4,4)
\psxTick{0}(-1){25}
\psxTick{0}(-2){50}
\psxTick{0}(-3){75}
\psxTick{0}(-4){100}
\psyTick{0}(-1){25}
\psyTick{0}(-2){50}
\psyTick{0}(-3){75}
\psyTick{0}(-4){100}
```

I imagine that this could be wrapped in a `multido` statement...

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: This is slightly unrelated but do you know why when I try to typeset this, I can't see the graph but only the labels (the numbers)?

Comment: @Alenanno did you copy and paste my code? it produces the output I gave in my screenshot

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. The same happens with the code from the OP... At first I had errors, then I updated my packages and that fixed the errors but I only see this ([link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2RXhg.png)) right now. :/

Comment: I do have pasted the complete code, that's the weird part. lol :P

Comment: are you compiling using xelatex ?

Comment: @cmhughes how to remove negative sign before number? ie -100 - 75 -50 -25

Comment: @PawanMude see the update

Comment: @PawanMude I think so, why?

Comment: @Aleanno: you used `pdflatex` instead of `xelatex`

Comment: @Alenanno you can try steps mentioned below : latex, dvips and finally ps2pdf will give you correct PDF